# Flash's AS3 Main Document Class as a dispatchEvent relay

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, events, listener, dispatcher

I need an event redispatcher at the top of the `DisplayObject` hierarchy.

Simple situation built from [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13792248/how-can-i-trigger-a-function-at-main-from-an-instanced-object-the-right-way) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028444/can-dispatchevent-carry-arguments-in-as3) of mine:

```
public class Main extends MovieClip { // Document Class at Flash
    private var objectA:ClassA;
    private var objectB:ClassB;

    public function Main() {
        objectA = new ClassA();
        addChild(objectA);
        objectB = new ClassB();
        addChild(objectB);
    }
}
```

```
public class ClassA extends Sprite {
    public function ClassA() {
        addChild(new Bitmap(new BitmapData(20, 20, false, 0))); // A black square
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickedA);
    }

    public function clickedA(evt:MouseEvent):void {
        dispatchEvent(new TextEvent("myEventType", true, false, "success"));
    }
}
```

```
public class ClassB extends Sprite {
    public function ClassB() {
        addEventListener("myEventType", myFunction);
    }

    public function myFunction(evt:TextEvent):void {
        trace(evt.text);
        var color:uint = evt.text == "success" ? 0x00FF00 : 0xFF0000;
        addChild(new Bitmap(new BitmapData(20, 20, false, color)));
    }
}
```

`myFunction` should react to the dispatch through `Main`.

What do I have to implement on `Main` to make it serve as a relay for dispatched events from a child to its other children?

Consider it can have many children as dispatchers and receivers/listeners. In other words, it has to be generic so I won't have to implement one relay for every case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution #1:**

Main:

```
objectB = new ClassB();
objectA = new ClassA(objectB);
```

ClassA:

```
objectB.myFunction("success");
```

ClassB:

```
public function myFunction(text:String):void {/*...*/}
```

---

**Solution #2:**

Main:

```
public var objectB:ClassB;
//objectB.name = "b";
```

ClassA:

```
var main = root;
//var main = stage.getChildAt(0);
//var main = stage.getChildByName("root1");

Main(main).objectB.myFunction("success");
//ClassB(Main(main).getChildByName("b")).myFunction("success");
```

ClassB:

```
public function myFunction(text:String):void {/*...*/}
```

Comment: Thank you! **Solution #2:** `Main(root).objectB.myFunction("success");` is everything I needed.

Answer (score 0):

in `ClassB` you should `addEventListener` to the main, for example if `var main` is a reference to the main class,

> main.addEventListener("myEventType", myFunction);

would be a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

You really don't want to patch all your events through `Main`, you just want to patch them through something.  A term for that something is an **event bus**.

There are some standalone event bus implementations out there (e.g., [as3commons-event-bus](http://www.as3commons.org/as3-commons-eventbus/introduction.html)), or you can move towards a full MVC framework (e.g. RobotLegs, PureMVC).

People differ in opinion about whether using event buses is a good thing.  It's handy for decoupled communication (pro), but it's usually a big singleton everyone subscribes to (con).